# Android RSS reader using SimpleXml and Retrofit - media:thumbnail parse issue

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, rss, simple-framework

How to parse the media:thumbnail url value from an RSSItem using simpleXml?

Here is my RSSItem class:

```
 @Root(name = "item", strict = false)
public class FeedItem {
    @Element(name = "pubDate")
    private String pubDate;
    @Element(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Element(name = "link")
    private String link;
    @Element(name = "description")
    private String description;


    public FeedItem() {
    }


    public FeedItem(String description, String link, String title, String pubDate) {
        this.description = description;
        this.link = link;
        this.title = title;
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

it all works ok, but I need to parse also the image url from the xml (media:thumbnail) here:

```
<media:thumbnail url="https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/gettyimages-591407481.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **@Attribute** annotation to get this.

In `<media:thumbnail ...>`, the *media* is a namespace and you only need to use *thumbnail* to access the content.

Example:

```
@Element(name = "thumbnail", required = false)
private Thumbnail thumbnail;

@Root(name = "thumbnail", strict = false)
static class Thumbnail {

    @Attribute(name = "url")
    private String url;
}
```